# How to transform sentence in interval using excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose that we have 3 excel cells that contains the following values :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm searching a built-in function / or a way to obtain the following output :

```
[1000,+INF]

[51,100]

[0,15]
```

I wich it's clear , i'm sorry because i'm not familiar with excel formula !

Thank you for help in advance !

Comment: You'll need to supply some more information about how the output is determined.  Where does the +INF come from in the first output? Where does the 0 come from in the third output?

Comment: My real positive variable is denoted as 'x' and i need to transform expressions to intervals : for example if x > 5 then the output will be [5, +inf ] where 'inf' means infinity // if x < 5 then   the output will be [0, 5 ]

Comment: Are the inputs always of the same form e.g. are either `Plus de X`, `Entre X et Y`, and `Moins de X`?

Comment: Will they always be in one of those three formats? (Plus de X, Entre X et Y, Moins de X)

Comment: @AlexP Jinx, you owe me a coke

Comment: @AlexP , yes the inputs are always the same !

Comment: @TouMou can you get rid of the "Personnes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (unwiedly and brittle) formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1)="P",CONCATENATE("[",MID(A1,LEN("Plus de ")+1,FIND("Personnes",A1,1)-2-LEN("Plus de ")),", +INF]",""),IF(LEFT(A1)="E",CONCATENATE("[",MID(A1,LEN("Entre ")+1,FIND("et",A1,1)-2-LEN("Entre ")),",",MID(A1,FIND("et",A1,1)+3,FIND("Personnes",A1,1)-1-FIND("et",A1,1)-3),"]"),IF(LEFT(A1)="M",CONCATENATE("[0, ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN("Moins de ")),"]"))))
```

Output:

```
        A                           B
1       Plus de 1000 Personnes      [1000, +INF]    
2       Entre 51 et 100 Personnes   [51, 100]
3       Moins de 15                 [0, 15]
```

This would be a lot easier and more robust if you could use VBA :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get rid of the "Personnes" at the end of 1 and 2, this should work for you.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Plus de ",A1)),CONCATENATE("[",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-8),",+INF]"),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Moins de ",A1)),CONCATENATE("[0,",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-9),"]"),CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Entre ","[")," et ",","),"]")))
```

Comment: thank you a lot for the precious help !